# Importar dados do Excel para o Mysql

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-excel, mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma importação de uma planilha do excel com 536 mil registros pelo mysql Workbench eu salvei a planilha como csv mas na hora da importação ele consegue importar todas as linhas mas ele puxa apenas a chave primária(CNPJ) e deixa todos os outros campos como 'NULL'

Aqui está a minha planilha

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem mais um campo pro lado que não da pra ver que é o campo 'Obs'.

E no banco ele importa apenas isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para fazer a importação estou utilizando esse código

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'importexcel/testeimport1.csv'
INTO TABLE checagens
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(CNPJ,DataCadastro,Razao,
 Operadora,Linhas,Classificacao,
 Vigencia,mesesContrato,Fidelidade,
 ValorGasto,FixoEmpresa,Gestor,
 Celular,FixoGestor,Email,Obs);
```

Comment: tenta mudar FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  por FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' (ponto e vírgula)

Comment: kkkk muito obrigado era isso mesmo, queria saber pq nao pode ser ',' mesmo mas beleza comenta como resposta ai

Comment: O método que importa deve estar como default o ; para divisão de célula ...acho que é isso não tenho certeza.  Geralmente funciona comigo dependendo do banco de dados...

Comment: Excel em línguas latinas utilizam o `;` como delimitador em arquivos csv